# How to always prepend dollar sign to value in text box

Tags: vb.net

I would like to always **add a $ sign inside a textbox when a user adds any number**.

My code look like this, but it is not working:

```
Private Sub capitalTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles capitalTB.TextChanged
    Dim cleanTXT As String
    If capitalTB.Text.StartsWith("$") = False Then
        cleanTXT = "$" & capitalTB.Text
        capitalTB.Text = cleanTXT
    End If
End Sub
```

When I key in the 2nd number it becomes something like this:
[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: Dont do it manually.  When you post a currency value use ToString: `someTB.Text = someAmount.ToString("C2")` it will display the proper currency symbol for the current culture.  Other than that "it is not working" does not describe a problem we can solve

Comment: You can use [`Currency-Masked-TextBox`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248989/A-Currency-Masked-TextBox-from-TextBox-Class) to use $ sign as you need.

Comment: You do know that append means adding the $ to the end of the string, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub capitalTB_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles capitalTB.TextChanged
    If capitalTB.Text.StartsWith("$") = False Then
        Dim SelStart As Integer

        SelStart = capitalTB.SelectionStart
        capitalTB.Text = "$" & capitalTB.Text
        capitalTB.SelectionStart = SelStart + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Try above code and for your learning: what you were missing was the cursor position when you reset the text of the textbox it puts your cursor to start of textbox (which is infact before your inserted $). I first stored cursor position in variable then assigned it back to textbox incremented by 1 because now there is another letter $.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles capitalTB.TextChanged
    Dim cleanTXT As String
    If capitalTB.Text.StartsWith("$") = False Then
        cleanTXT = "$" & Replace(capitalTB.Text, "$", "")
        capitalTB.Text = cleanTXT
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it work for one digit number, but when i entered 123, it become $321

Comment: @David you cant debug this yourself??! Seriously easiest question EVER! If you want to learn programming this is a great first step to solve this yourself.

Comment: im totally new to VB.net

Comment: Ok - with a Java background please do yourself a favor and just use C#. And there is other code you're not showing us for 123 to return 321. There is no way this code will reverse the string.

Comment: i have other code for keypress event which check: If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question, solved with this

```
 Private Sub capitalTB_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles capitalTB.Validating
        Dim currency As Decimal

        'Convert the current value to currency, with or without a currency symbol.
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(Me.capitalTB.Text, _
                                Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, _
                                Nothing, _
                                currency) Then
            'Don't let the user leave the field if the value is invalid.
            With Me.capitalTB
                .HideSelection = False
                .SelectAll()

                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid capital amount.", _
                                "Invalid Capital", _
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
                                MessageBoxIcon.Error)

                .HideSelection = True
            End With

            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub capitalTB_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                   ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles capitalTB.Validated
        'Display the value as local currency.
        Me.capitalTB.Text = Decimal.Parse(Me.capitalTB.Text).ToString("c")
    End Sub
```

thanks to @Avijit currency masked.